# Is it possible to interchange different of fuels for turbine engines?

Tags: fuel, turbine

There are a few types of fuel for turbine engines, for example Jet-A, Jet A-1 and Jet-B.

Is it safe / practical to interchange these types of fuel for a generic turbine engine?

Comment: Flash point, freezing point... All in that [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpGrH.png).

Comment: hello there, please do not re-ask questions that are closed by the community; it does not work here. Instead, the closed question should be reworked to be reopened by the community. I side with you that it is not a duplicate, but if enough people disagree, then the question should be edited further to clarify. **TL;DR**: *repeated attempts of the same circumstances is unlikely to result in a different outcome*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking generic turbine engines then the answer is yes. Turbine engines will run on a wide range of fuels, I personally have flown a Military Helicopter, that normally runs on Jet A1 using AVGAS instead. The flight manual limited it to 10 hours of operation on AVGAS. Interestingly the same flight manual had other fuel types listed such as Deisel, and automotive gasoline.

The only difference I noticed on the different fuel was a slightly higher exhaust gas temperature for a given power setting.

Heavy duty industrial turbines are often run off crude oil!